# WordPress Parent Child Custom Permalink Rewrite

Tags: regex, wordpress, permalinks, wp-rewrite

Hi I have two custom post types, I am using the parent-child relationship between both like as,

1. store_name (parent)
2. store_offer (child)

I want to rewrite the permalink for the both like as

1. sitename.com/store/store_name
2. sitename.com/store/store_name/store_offer

Also, if there is no parent post specified then URL structure should be

3. sitename.com/store/global/store_offer

I have tried many tutorials but no luck. I just want to know what will be the correct "add_rewrite_rule" for those permalink structures?

Comment: Ok, so what can we do to help? Step back and read your question as if you have no preconceived knowledge about your question, there's no question and it's unclear what you want from us.

Comment: Hi, I simply want those permalinks structures to work. so what will be the correct rewrite rules (add_rewrite_rule) for those?  Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule